# Visualforce dynamic Ids assignment

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I am trying to work on  component. Currently, I have this as the structure:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Document">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!documents}" var="doc">
                    <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!doc.id}">{!doc.name}.{!doc.Type}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!doc.Description}"/>                  
                </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

I would like to add a new column to this table, "Job Status".

```
<apex:column headervalue="Job status"> 
                            <apex:outputText id="{!doc.id}"></apex:outputtext>
                        </apex:column>
```

This throws an error stating that id requires a literal value. I intend to use this id to peg the job status with the current document. However, I have run into this issue and seems I will not be able to track this info from the apex class. What other ways that I can add an additional column that has no information to deal with the page table variable?

Comment: how are jobs and documents related to each other?

Comment: @Anshul I am uploading the documents to a local web server. That is the definition for the job. So, one upload job per document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement is to include a new column, wrap the object inside a class and include any custom properties that is required. This is the solution I have developed to include in the table:

```
 class DocObj
    {
        SObject sObj;
        String status;

        public DocObj(SObject sObj)
        {
            this.sObj = sObj;
            this.status = 'Not begun';
        }

        public SObject getsObj()
        {
            return sObj;
        }

        public String getStatus()
        {
            return status;
        }

    }
```

Since this deals with working on the Apex classes, this is the probable solution. Else, you can go with sfdcfox's solution to manipulate from the script.

Answer (score 2):

The "id" attribute for any element with a "managed" XML namespace (e.g. apex:outputText, c:myComponent, etc), can never use non-literal values. This is because these id values must be unique and may be referenced from other locations, such as reRender targets or the $Component global variable. Instead, simply use a normal span tag, such as: `<span id="{!doc.id}"></span>`.

Comment: If I have to manipulate the value in Apex, can this be done without creating a Map<DocId,JobStatus>?

Comment: Got a 5 minute limit, let me elaborate. After the process is complete, I have to update the status along with the table info. Generally, we can fire using {!varName} to manipulate the value and <Apex:Repeat> to use the lists. I have to modify the particular span's ID from Apex class. How do I do that?

Comment: @dmachop Depends on what you're trying to do, but if you're rendering client-side, you'll want to use unmanaged elements anyways, and if you're using managed elements, you can just set the status/result value in the Map and render that map using apex:repeat.